# Microsoft Release Management 2013 access username of the user triggering the release

Tags: email, powershell, variables, release-management, ms-release-management

I am trying to add a step to execute a powershell script to the release management release template to send customized email on each release. I want to pass in the username of the user who triggered the release, are there any inbuilt variables that manage the username of the user who triggered the release and can be accessed when the workflow is being executed?

Answer (score 0):

All system variables that are provided by MS Release Management can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn834972.aspx), and the user triggering the release doesn't appear to be part of them, I'm afraid.